# How to format date and display month and day based on user language

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am trying to display the date and time in javascript based on users browser language preference. I am receiveing the date in UTC format and by using toLocaleString() i am able to convert it to browser time zone. But i also need to convert the day name and month name to browser language.

For ex

6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> Monday, June 15, 2009 8:45:30 PM (en-US)
6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> den 15 juni 2009 20:45:30 (sv-SE)
6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> Δευτέρα, 15 Ιουνίου 2009 8:45:30 μμ (el-GR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want consistent output regardless of browser, moment.js is a good option.

```
// set the desired language
moment.lang('sv');

// use one of the localized format strings
var s = moment(yourDate).format('LLLL');
```

There are live examples on the [moment.js home page](http://momentjs.com/), showing all of the available languages.  I don't believe there is currently support for Greek, but since it is open-source you could always add it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Using [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) you can do this:

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

// request a weekday along with a long date
var options = {weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric"};
alert(date.toLocaleString("de-DE", options));
// → "Donnerstag, 20. Dezember 2012"

// an application may want to use UTC and make that visible
options.timeZone = "UTC";
options.timeZoneName = "short";
alert(date.toLocaleString("en-US", options));
// → "Thursday, December 20, 2012, GMT"
```