# How to convert Datetime to text Date JS

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to convert my full datetime to text date using js, example my input is 17/01/2020 and my output should be "January 17" with or whitout the year for me is the same. Any ideas how can I Achive this?

Is the same if the solution cames in C# or JS I can convert the date in the  controller or the view

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format date and display month and day based on user language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541409/how-to-format-date-and-display-month-and-day-based-on-user-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return exactly what you're looking for

```js
let today  = new Date();
let options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options));
```

> The **toLocaleDateString()** method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the date portion of this date.

There are more options, If you want for example the weekday, year, etc...

for more info check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "MMMM" custom format specifier in C#. This specifier represents full name of the month.
example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd");
```

Here "dd" is representing day number.